# Quickly finding array element by pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of strings where each string can also be clearly identified by a unique pointer assigned to it. The order of the elements in that array often changes, for example because of sorting.

I want to be able to quickly find the numeric index of an array item just from its accompanying pointer. For example, after sorting the array in the code below, I'd like to have 0 for `0xfeedface`, 1 for `0xc0decafe` and 2 for `0xdeadbeef`. Of course, I don't want to iterate over all elements and manually compare the pointer values because that would be too slow in the real life application. So how can I do that please?

I need a solution that still allows me to use `std::sort` to sort the items and I also don't have C++11 on my target platform so the solution should not require C++11 or higher. Thanks for your help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

class RowItem
{
public:
   RowItem(std::string text, void *ptr) : m_text(text), m_ptr(ptr) {}
   std::string GetText() {return m_text;}
private:
   std::string m_text;
   void *m_ptr;
};
    
class RowCmp
{
public:
   RowCmp() {}
                    
   bool operator()(RowItem &first, RowItem &second) const
   {
    return first.GetText().compare(second.GetText()) < 0;   
   }
};

int main()
{   
    std::vector<RowItem> v;
    RowItem one("C\n", (void *) 0xdeadbeef), two("B\n", (void *) 0xc0decafe), three("A\n", (void *) 0xfeedface);
    
    v.push_back(one);
    v.push_back(two);
    v.push_back(three);
    
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), RowCmp());                    
    
    for(size_t k = 0; k < v.size(); k++) std::cout << v[k].GetText();       

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I need a solution that still allows me to use std::sort* -- What if you kept the vector as-is, and sorted an array of indices that point to the items instead?  Then the order of the elements wouldn't change (i.e. physically, `deadbeef` is still at 0, but will be at `index[0]` in the sorted position).

Comment: Like it or not, without a ordering on `m_ptr` and/or a map keying on said-same (and thus ordering comes along for the ride), the thing you said, *"...would be too slow in the real life application."* is the only option you have. An unordered sequence of values (that they are pointers is irrelevant) that *must* be searched for an equivalence by-definition is an O(n) degenerate algorithm. Only if the encompassing container is sorted by said-value (e.g. sorted by m_ptr), or a map that shares content (index is fine) with the original container, is going to rescue you from that cold reality.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I don't understand how that would help because AFAIU I'd still need to iterate over all elements and compare the pointer values, wouldn't I?

Comment: @WhozCraig: I'm not too familiar with C++. AFAIU you suggest to create a `std::map` to  use the pointers as numeric keys for the string values? Is that right? I don't really know how I would implement this in practice, though, because I also need to be able to sort everything and AFAIU that's not really possible with `std::map`, is it?

Comment: @Andreas All you need to do is build an initial map with the pointer and positions in the vector.  There is no need to do a linear search, since you know that, for example, the `deadbeef` would be in the sorted position at `index[map[deadbeef]]`.  The issue is that you need extra space for the map and index array.  Think of how a database does these things.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: And for the map I should use `std::map` or how would you do that? As I said, I'm a beginner in C++...

Comment: @Andreas `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Unfortunately, I'm still struggling with this. It's hard to imagine this just from an explanation without any code. IIUC you suggest that I should set up an `std::map` where the key `0xdeadbeef` contains position 0, `0xc0decafe` contains position 1, and `0xfeedface` contains position 2. But after sorting I somehow need those positions to change, so that `0xdeadbeef` is now 2 and `0xfeedface` is 0. But I don't understand how I could do that. Maybe some code would help because I'm having a hard time understanding exactly how to adapt the map when sorting the main array. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Ok, I think I got it now. I've posted my implementation as an answer. Can you check if that's what you suggested? Thanks!

Comment: Usually, you need an array index in order to access an element of the array. Here, it seems that you have the element and are looking to determine its index, which may change over time. That all seems slow and error-prone unless you can guarantee that the array won't be modified before the index is used. I'd guess you need the index to pass to some function(s) that will then use it to retrieve the element itself, which you already have. If so, your time will be better spent refactoring that code to allow you to pass the element directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with after Paul's explanations in the comments. It seems to do the trick. As suggested by Paul, it doesn't sort the original vector but keeps that as it is. Since the positions in the original vector now stay the same, we can use a simple map to map the pointer values to the corresponding index.

All that's left to do now is to merely sort an array of indices referencing the strings in the original vector. After that is done we can easily find the new position of an item using its pointer value by just peeking into the sorted indices vector.

In code, it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

class RowItem
{
public:
   RowItem(std::string text, void *ptr) : m_text(text), m_ptr(ptr) {}
   std::string GetText() const {return m_text;} 
private:
   std::string m_text;
   void *m_ptr;
};

class RowCmp
{
public:
   RowCmp(std::vector<RowItem> &v) : m_v(v) {}
                    
   bool operator()(int first, int second) const
   {
    return m_v[first].GetText().compare(m_v[second].GetText()) < 0;     
   }
   
private:
   std::vector<RowItem> m_v;   
};

int main()
{   
    std::vector<RowItem> v;
    std::vector<int> index;
    RowItem one("C\n", (void *) 0xdeadbeef), two("B\n", (void *) 0xc0decafe), three("A\n", (void *) 0xfeedface);

    index.push_back(0);
    index.push_back(1);
    index.push_back(2);
    
    v.push_back(one);
    v.push_back(two);
    v.push_back(three);
    
    std::map<unsigned __int64, int> pmap;
    pmap[0xdeadbeef] = 0;    
    pmap[0xc0decafe] = 1;   
    pmap[0xfeedface] = 2;   
            
    std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(), RowCmp(v));                   
    
    for(size_t k = 0; k < v.size(); k++) std::cout << v[index[k]].GetText();        

    std::cout << "Deadbeef at: " << index[pmap[0xdeadbeef]] << "\n";
    std::cout << "Codecafe at: " << index[pmap[0xc0decafe]] << "\n";
    std::cout << "Feedface at: " << index[pmap[0xfeedface]] << "\n";
                
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind.   Some minor changes -- you should have `#include <algorithm>`, and also replace `unsigned __int64` with `uint64_t`.  Once you do that, then the code [runs correctly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbf4a3d4ca8a60b7).  Also, you could use `std::vector<int> index(3);` and then `std::iota(index.begin(), index.end(), 0);` to initialize the index vector.  Also I suggest you explain what you did (basically use my comments as a guide), so that this looks less like a code-only answer, but one that others can learn from.

Comment: Ok, I've added some explanations. The code does compile without warnings on my old Visual C++ so I'm leaving any adaptation to other compilers as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: Leaving out `<algorithm>` is really an error -- that's where `std::sort` is declared.   Also, `uint64_t` is part of [C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), so unless you're using an older standard, all C++11 standard compilers support it.

Comment: Ok, added `<algorithm>`. As mentioned in the OP, I'm still on a very old compiler that doesn't have C++11 at all...

Comment: OK, no problem.  That's probably why you used `std::map` instead of `std::unordered_map`.